# How to fix SolrException: Error loading solr config?

Tags: linux, solr, tomcat7

So, my current setup looks like this:

Solr 4.10.4 with Tomcat7. Solr by itself is woring under `localhost:8080/solr` but as it wants to create a core it gets the following failure:

```
SolrCore Initialization Failures
atalanda_development: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core atalanda_development: Error loading solr config from /usr/share/solr/example/solr/development/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

So the first thought of mine was to check if the file is even there:

```
ll /usr/share/solr/example/solr/development/conf/solrconfig.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tomcat7 gbeschbacher 71K Mar 16 13:56 /usr/share/solr/example/solr/development/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

So after this i knew the file was there and tomcat7 has the permission on it. I tried two versions of solrconfig.xml - a default one and a custom one. The error occured with both of these.

My Tomcat7 has the following solr.xml file which is pretty straight forward:

```
cat /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml 
<Context docBase="/usr/share/solr/example/solr/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
    <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr/example/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

All it does it to tell tomcat7 where my docbase and my environment of solr is. For more understanding i show you the folder-structure with the permissions of my `usr/share/solr/example/solr` folder:

```
/u/s/s/e/solr ❯❯❯
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat7 gbeschbacher 4.0K Sep  8  2014 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat7 gbeschbacher 4.0K Mar 18 23:06 collection1
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat7 root         4.0K Mar 19 00:53 development
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 gbeschbacher 2.5K Sep  8  2014 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 gbeschbacher  29M Mar 19 00:13 solr.war
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 gbeschbacher  333 Mar 19 00:52 solr.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 gbeschbacher  501 Sep  8  2014 zoo.cfg
```

In here, the `solr.xml` contains the following code:

```
/u/s/s/e/solr ❯❯❯ cat solr.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <solr persistent="false">
        <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
            <core name="atalanda_development" instanceDir="development" dataDir="development/data"/>
        </cores>
    </solr>
```

So, at the moment i really have no clue anymore what i still could try to get my setup to work because i don't know what i am doing wrong in here. Any suggestions or try-out solutions are appreciated even it's only a comment on what i could change.

If someone needs any more information to be able to give some hints, please tell me so and I'll provide it!

Comment: The error is not complete I guess. Error `Could not load conf` doesn't mean the file is not there, but there is a problem parsing it. If you've still the problem, you should check for the main error further down.

Comment: In your `solr.xml` is a setting pointing to `dataDir="development/data"`, how about the permissions there?

Comment: Permissions were all set to tomcat; I couldn't figure out the main error though.. all i did was switching to sunspot:solr and it works.